# mysql: get distinct value of TEXT

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get unique message (datatype: `TEXT`). I am using this simple query to achieve this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT message FROM `online_communication`
```

Results I am getting are:

```
hello.. what's up?
second message..
third message.....
third message.....
```

Why am I getting `third message.....` 2 times? I also tried with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT BINARY message FROM `online_communication`
```

But, getting same number of rows in `BLOB`

PS: No luck with `GROUP BY` as well.

**SQLFiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/304e4/1

Comment: This is very strange. Can you recreate the table in SQLFiddle and do you get the same values? It's hard to understand without seeing this one in action.

Comment: SELECT message, hex(message) FROM `online_communications` -- this will show you the binary representation of your strings, they got to be different, just appear the same

Comment: @McAdam331: Please check SQLFIDDLE.

Comment: have you tried applying a RTRIM / LTRIM to make sure there are no spaces?

Comment: @SamAbushanab: No, i didn't . Let me try on fiddle

Comment: @RonakPatel this behaves as expected, the lines are different. one has a space and one doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is behaving as expected because your values *are* different. From your SQL fiddle:

```
INSERT INTO `online_communication` (`id`, `company_id`, `country_id`, `message`, `date_added`, `time_interval`) VALUES
(53, 1, 210, 'third message.....\r\nand here..\r\n', '2015-05-01 11:05:31', '1'),
(61, 1, 103, 'third message.....\r\nand here.. \r\n', '2015-05-01 11:06:38', '1');
```

Notice that the first insert does not have a space after the two periods, but the second one does. They look the same in the results, because the difference just represents white space.

**EDIT**

By definition, these *are* unique messages, so your query is fine. However, if you want to treat them as the same, you need to find a business rule for what defines them as the same.

For example, you could just remove all spaces from the string, and compare them that way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(message, ' ', '') FROM `online_communication`
```

Here is a working [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/304e4/5) example.

Here are some helpful [string](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) functions. Notice that you cannot use `TRIM()` here because that function only removes whitespace from the beginning or end of a string. In this example, it is in the middle, so `REPLACE` is more useful.

Comment: Ya. That's the data inserted by user. But, how can I avoid that extra space while getting data? What should I do to get unique messages?

Comment: @RahulTripathi: Itried with: `SELECT DISTINCT trim(message) FROM online_communication` still it's giving me double messages

Comment: @RahulTripathi TRIM will not work here, because the white space is inside the string and not on either end of it. `REPLACE()` is the string function you are looking for.

Comment: @RonakPatel:- Yes instead use `REPLACE(message, ' ', '')`

Comment: And I can not display that message without any spaces to users

Comment: @RonakPatel I have updated my answer to get you the results you need.

Comment: @RonakPatel you do not need GROUP BY. It will do the same thing as `DISTINCT` in this particular example. Since the values are not the same, they cannot be grouped, unless you group using replace syntax as well.

Comment: But, As I mentioned, I can not display messages without spaces to users.. If I will use this then it'll solve all problems.. `SELECT message FROM online_communication
GROUP BY REPLACE(message, ' ', '')` It'll give me results with spaces and unique.

Comment: How about SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(message, ' \r\n', '\r\n') FROM `online_communication`

Comment: @RonakPatel sure, but what that will do is arbitrarily select one of the two messages. Try selecting ID instead of message with that code and you will see that only one of the two messages is returned.

Answer (score 1):

One of your line has an extra space

```
(53, 1, 210, 'third message.....\r\nand here..\r\n', '2015-05-01 11:05:31', '1'),
(61, 1, 103, 'third message.....\r\nand here.. \r\n', '2015-05-01 11:06:38', '1');
```

Remove that and you will get the expected result.

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc707/1)**

Comment: Ya. That's the data inserted by user. But, how can I avoid that extra space while getting data? What should I do to get unique messages?

Answer (score 0):

Are there any spaces at the end of the one of the instances of "third message....."?  According to [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html), trailing spaces aren't removed from TEXT types.  You could check with a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT concat('[', message,  ']') FROM `online_communication`
```

You'll be looking for something like this in the results:

```
[hello.. what's up?]
[second message..]
[third message.....]
[third message.....   ]
```

Comment: I tried that. I can not find any difference. Can you please check in on sqlfiddle.

Comment: You got a bunch of answers all at once - I see others have looked at the data and pointed out the specific extra space.